# How to enumerate all positive rationals (strictly) less than a given value

Tags: combinatorics, rational-numbers

It is well known that all positive rationals can be generated by traversing the [Stern Brocot tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree).

How might this be modified to produce all positive rationals *strictly less than* a given value?

Comment: Call the given value $a$. Then, if there exists an algorithm enumerating rationals smaller than $a$, necessarily $a$ is computable.

Comment: Traverse the tree an omit the rationals not less than the threshold.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the left half of the Stern-Brocot tree consists of all and only positive rational numbers strictly less than one.

So if you want to enumerate all positive rational numbers less than a particular rational number $q > 0$, you could simply traverse the left half of the Stern-Brocot tree and multiply those results by $q$.

Comment: There is also the case where the bounding value is irrational.

Comment: The bounding value may be a non-computable real number $a$. In such a case, there is no algorithm enumerating $\{ x \in \Bbb{Q} : x < a \}$.

Answer (score 0):

I intended to post this as a comment as I'm not sure this is a satisfactory answer, but it was too long. If your bound is written as a (possibly infinite) continued fraction

$$a = [a_0, a_1,a_2, \ldots] = a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1+\frac{1}{a_2+_{\ddots}}}$$

You can compute the Stern-Brocot tree and throw away the nodes that are above that bound. Of course, if a node is thrown away (or is exactly the bound $a$), you need not compute the right descendants, but you may need to compute the left descendants.

To compare two continued fractions $a = [a_0, a_1,a_2, \ldots]$ and $b = [b_0, b_1,b_2, \ldots]$, compare the sequences $((-1)^k a_k)$ and $((-1)^k b_k)$ in lexicographical order : Compare $a_0$ and $b_0$ ($a_0 > b_0$, then $a > b$), if they are equal then compare $-a_1$ and $-b_1$, if they are equal compare $a_2$ and $b_2$ and so on...